# Measure theory book suggestion similar to Zorich's Analysis I and II

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, book-recommendation

I am into studying Zorich's mathematical analysis books and I am really enjoying it mainly because it pushes the reader to understand deeper results based on simpler ones. I would like to know if anyone could suggest me a measure theory book similar to it with the purpose of studying advanced probability.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I haven't read Zorich myself, but Dudley's "Real Analysis and Probability" starts from scratch and has its second half on more advanced probability.

Comment: Also consider Billingsley's *Probability and Measure* and Williams's *Probability with Martingales*. Durrett's *Probability* provides a minimal course on measure theory in his first chapter.